Выдает ошибку RuntimeWarning
Пытаюсь создать множественный чек. Не получается, прошу по
import asyncio
import aiocryptopay
api=aiocryptopay.AioCryptoPay(token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", network=aiocryptopay.Networks.MAIN_NET)
async def gggggg():
        return api.create_invoice(asset="USDT", amount=None)
asyncio.run(gggggg())

Ошибка:
/root/asdasdsad/invice.py:6: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AioCryptoPay.create_invoice' was never awaited
  asyncio.run(gggggg())
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback


Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Что корутину нужно ожидать.

Попробуйте добавить await после return. По приставке aio можно понять, что библиотека асинхронная, а значит и методы класса в этой библиотеки тоже будут асинхронными, о чём нам и говорит ошибка: "Корутина не была за await`чена".
import asyncio
import aiocryptopay

api=aiocryptopay.AioCryptoPay(
    token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    network=aiocryptopay.Networks.MAIN_NET
)

async def func():
        return await api.create_invoice(asset="USDT", amount=None)
asyncio.run(func())

